# Check and uncheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to right check and uncheck checkboxes? 
I have many troubles with it.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/N5Swt/ :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /> <span> Check me! </span>

// test1
/*$('#checkbox1').attr('checked','true');
$('#checkbox1').attr('checked','false');*/ // This line doesnt work

// test2
$('#checkbox1').attr('checked','true');
$('#checkbox1').removeAttr('checked');
$('#checkbox1').attr('checked','true'); //This line doesnt work
```

It doesnt work. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**jQuery:**

You can use jQuery's [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

`$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);`

to uncheck you'd just use:

`$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);`

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5Swt/4/)

---

**Pure Javascript:**

In pure Javascript you could use the .checked property:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked = true;
```

to uncheck you'd just use:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked = false;
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dy9Q3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checkbox value and not attr.

And you are setting a Boolean so you should not be using a string to set the property's value.

```
$('#checkbox1').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also address the element property directly:

```
document.querySelector('#checkbox1').checked = true;
// or
$('#checkbox1')[0].checked = true;
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/dy9Q3/) demo

Answer (score 1):

better use native javascript property
its clear and always works

```
$('#checkbox1')[0].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working...

```
$('#checkbox1').attr('checked',true);
$('#checkbox1').attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: This works but when you add another attr() line to the context, it just fails - as tested by topic raiser.